# Office 365 SharePoint, Copy folders and maintain direct access permissions?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, permissions, office-365

Title says most of it, I created a folder and a bunch of subfolders then gave people direct access to each of them.

It's basically a template that I want to copy/paste and modify the name.

"Copy To" doesn't maintain direct access permissions, how do I effectively copy/paste a retain them properly?

Answer (score 0):

Copy to will not keep permissions. If you want to set a unique permission on quite a bunch of places, I think it may be better to use a CSOM/PNP powershell script to handle it. Here are some samples you can refer to. [SharePoint Online: Set Folder Permissions using PowerShell](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/09/sharepoint-online-set-folder-permissions-powershell.html)

Or simply you can put all the actions in one script: 
[How to Copy a Folder in SharePoint Online using PowerShell?](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/04/copy-folder-in-sharepoint-online-using-powershell.html)